# back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, superclass

I try to go to previous Activity (Activity A) but have problem. Command to this get inside Activity B and I wont to go back to B:

A:

```
if(...)
{
   B.staticF();
}
```

B:

```
static void staticF()
{
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

But I can't use super because it's static context.

Of course, I can call

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but I wont to save B look.

Comment: try by adding this.youractivityname in intent.

Comment: I prefer to use a "global" state like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/862629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use something like a shared preference to save the state? and then use the intent to go back and in the onCreate method get the preferences and populate any views with the data you wanted to save

Comment: Unless there is no more easier way?

Comment: Hmm, that is what I would do and Im pretty experienced with android, what is in the UI of activity B?

Comment: public class B extends Activity
{
...
}

Comment: Have you ever considered using fragments?

Comment: I'm 3 months in android.

I wont set B data in activity C and get it out A